# What's the difference between ngx.thread.spawn(func) and ngx.timer.at(0, func)?

Tags: nginx, lua

What's the difference between `ngx.thread.spawn(func)` and `ngx.timer.at(0, func)` (except the first "premature" argument in the second case, of course)?

Why `ngx.timer.at()` can be used in, for instance, `init_worker_by_lua`, while `ngx.thread.spawn()` can't? And why `tcpsock:connect()` can be used inside `ngx.timer.at()`, but not inside `ngx.thread.spawn()`?